# Java Error: <identifier> expected inside protected interface

Tags: java

I am facing the following problem. I was trying to put together a simple tutorial on the strategy in Java when I ran into a problem. 
The compiler gives me an "<identifier> expected" error on the `void do(int i);` in the interface: 
Here is the full class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Data {
private List<Integer> ints;

  public Data( int[] a ) {
    ints = new LinkedList<>(); 
    for( int i : a ) ints.add( i );
 }

 protected static interface Strategy{
    void do(int i);
 }

 protected void loop( Strategy s ) {
        for( int i : ints ) {
            s.do( i );
        }
    }
 }
```

Why am I getting this error? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Define the Strategy interface outside of the Data class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name `do` is a [Java keyword (Section 3.9, JLS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) and can't be a method name.  Change your method name to something not a keyword.

```
protected static interface Strategy{
    void doAction(int i);
}
```